# How to normalize data which contain positive and negative numbers into 0 and 1?

Tags: python, data-analysis, normalization

I have a dataset that contains negative and positive values. then here I use MinMaxScaler() to normalize the data to 0 and 1. but because the normalized data has negative and positive values in it, the normalization is not optimal, so the resulting prediction results are not optimal. then I try to change the negative data to positive with abs() then the result from abs() is normalized using MinMaxScaler() the result will be better. is there a way for me to keep the negative and positive values but have good predictions?

my last activation function is **Sigmoid**

Here my model structure:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64, activation='relu',  return_sequences= False, input_shape= (50,89)))
model.add(Dense(32,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(16,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.002), metrics=['mse'])
model.summary()
```

[model structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OKMC.png)

Here my code of normalization with abs():

```
df = pd.read_csv('1113_Rwalk40s1.csv', low_memory=False)
columns = ['Fx', 'Fy', 'Fz', 'Mx', 'My', 'Mz']]
selected_df = df[columns]
FCDatas = selected_df[:2050]
FCDatas = abs(FCDatas)

SmartInsole = np.array(SIData[:2050])
FCData = np.array(FCDatas)
Dataset = np.concatenate((SmartInsole, FCData), axis=1)

scaler_in = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaler_out = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
data_scaled_in = scaler_in.fit_transform(Dataset[:,0:89])
data_scaled_out = scaler_out.fit_transform(Dataset[:,89:90])
```

[The result using abs()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUwpR.png)

Here my code of normalization with without abs():

```
df = pd.read_csv('1113_Rwalk40s1.csv', low_memory=False)
columns = ['Fx', 'Fy', 'Fz', 'Mx', 'My', 'Mz']]
selected_df = df[columns]
FCDatas = selected_df[:2050]

SmartInsole = np.array(SIData[:2050])
FCData = np.array(FCDatas)
Dataset = np.concatenate((SmartInsole, FCData), axis=1)

scaler_in = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaler_out = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
data_scaled_in = scaler_in.fit_transform(Dataset[:,0:89])
data_scaled_out = scaler_out.fit_transform(Dataset[:,89:90])
```

[The result without abs()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZbzy.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can change the [range](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html) of `MinMaxScaler` to be between `[-1,1]`, if you'd like to keep the smallest number (negative in your case) still negative, but the largest number still positive. Does this help?